# Gas fireplace - moved a lever and it shut off the fireplace

Tags: gas, fireplace

We had recently bought a house and turned on the gas fireplace.

[image]

I thought we might need to open a flue so I looked in the fireplace and saw a lever on the top.  I moved it to the left and the fireplace went out.  The pilot light is still on but now the fireplace won't light.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you move the lever back?  Pictures would help us identify the function

Comment: I did move the lever back.  How do I add pictures to this post?

Comment: Since your rep is low, upload the pic to imgur.com and just  post the link here, someone with higher rep will edit it into the question for you.

Comment: Here is the link...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/iag9U

Comment: Nevermind - it is working now!!!  Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Please let us know how you solved your problem by posting it as an answer, so that future people with your same difficulty will be helped by your experience. Thanks!